# Folder param in Facebook graph API /*page-id/conversations

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get all Conversations for a certain Page on Facebook using the Graph API (python):

```
token= "*ACCESS TOKEN*"
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token)

result = graph.request("*PAGE ID*/conversations")
data = result['data']
paging = result['paging']
next = paging['next']
```

I then iterate and call

```
result = graph.request(next)
```

My problem is that I only get conversations from the last two months and only from the inbox.

I see that the conversations method has a folder param.. but I can't seem to get it to work. Anyone know how to get more conversations? With or without the folder param?